# Java StringOutOfBounds Error in loop only

Tags: java, string

Here's some code i'm trying to make work.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            String line = reader.readLine(); // start with the first line
            String[] a = new String[3];

        a = line.split(" ");
        int n = a[0].charAt(0) - '0';
        int m = a[1].charAt(0) - '0';
        int k = a[2].charAt(0) - '0';

        DisjointUnionSets dus = new DisjointUnionSets(n);
        line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null)
        {
            String[] b = new String[2];
            b = line.split(" ");
            int tmp1 = b[0].charAt(0) - '0';
            int tmp2 = b[1].charAt(0) - '0';
            dus.union(tmp1,tmp2);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();

        // Check if 4 is a neighbour of 1
        if (dus.find(4) == dus.find(1))
            System.out.println("Yes");
        else
            System.out.println("No");

        // Check if 1 is a neighbour of 2
        if (dus.find(1) == dus.find(2))
            System.out.println("Yes");
        else
            System.out.println("No");
    }
catch(IOException ex){}
}
}
```

It compiles with no errors but when I try to run it, I get an exception when defining tmp1:

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

I really can't understand why this doesn't happen when I define n,m and k. I use b the same way I use a, at least that's what I think.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: give you input as well

Comment: tell the command with which you are trying to run the code ?

Comment: My input is 3 numbers in the first line then lines of two numbers. Numbers are separated by one space. @Nixal Saxena not sure exactly what you mean but I simply run Java main input.txt from a terminal if that's your question.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `null` check, also check if `line` contains only spaces. If it does, then length of the array `b` would be 0.

Comment: I will check but I think the problem is not there(there's not such a line). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok. You could also try setting up a debug point inside the `while` loop to find out the value of the array `b`.

Answer (score 0):

With `line.split(" ")` you will get empty strings in your result array if the words in `line` are separated by more than one blank.  Try

```
b = line.split("\\s+");
```

instead.  It matches one ore more (`+`) whitespace (`\s`) characters.

The reason you are having a problem in one instance and not another is line-to-line differences in the input.  On lines where a single space was used, when you hit a line where more than one space was used, kaboom!

Comment: I 'll give it a shot but as I specified in the comment above about my input it doesn't contain more than one blanks.

Comment: @cgss if you're input is indeed as you say, this won't help your immediate situation, but it's a handy trick to know for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Combining both answers from Kevin Anderson and Anish Kanchan I came up with this:

```
while(line != null && !(line.matches("\\s*")))
```

Now it works fine and I assume the problem was encountered right after reading the last line. I think that instead of creating a null string as intended it created an empty one. So I am not sure if I solve the problem or just hide it. That's why I haven't accept any answers yet.(I did upvoted them though)